# Функция mail() ошибка

Tags: php, localhost, xampp

Здравствуйте
Хочу протестировать отправку почты с локалки, именно так,но...

Произошло вот такое после запуска в браузере index.php:

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 13
Произошла ошибка(
```

Что мне исправить в php.ini?:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

    ; For Win32 only.
    ; http://php.net/sendmail-from
    sendmail_from = me@mail.ru

    ; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
    ; http://php.net/sendmail-path
    ;sendmail_path =
```

Comment: Судя по сообщению об ошибке, Вы забыли запустить свой SMTP-сервер.

Comment: А как именно это сделать в xampp не подскажете?

Comment: Напиши в вопросе, что используется сборка xampp. А не "локалка".

Answer (score 0):

> Хочу протестировать отправку почты с локалки,

На Windows-сборках АМР ([WAMP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP)) в php нет phpmail. Отправлять просто нечем. Есть эмуляторы и стороннее ПО. Напр денвер - тот письма в файл пишет.

А в данном коде вообще указано использование SMPT-сервера. Для его разворачивания нужно использовать другое ПО.